# clicking a separate button that isn't part of the 'close' button fire's the close event anyways

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an announcement bar that has a center button linking to another site. It also has a 'close' button on the far right. When I click the center button, the close button gets fired as well.

I tested to see if it's because I'm encapsulating the `#close` div within by removing it out of the `#bar` div but it still caused the same issue.

```js
var closeBar = document.getElementById("close");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
if (closeBar) {
  addEventListener('click', function() {
    bar.classList.add('superHidden');
  })
}
```

```css
#bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.superHidden {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="google.com"><button >Google</button></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="close">
    <ul>
      <li>X</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not specifying a target for the event listener, so you're adding a click event to *the entire window*:

```
addEventListener('click', function() {
    bar.classList.add('superHidden');
})
```

If you click anywhere on the window, this event is triggered.

It sounds like you want to add the event just to the "close button":

```
closeBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    bar.classList.add('superHidden');
})
```

Full example:

```js
var closeBar = document.getElementById("close");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");
if (closeBar) {
  closeBar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    bar.classList.add('superHidden');
  })
}
```

```css
#bar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: auto 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#close {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.superHidden {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="google.com"><button >Google</button></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="close">
    <ul>
      <li>X</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: derp. That was actually fairly obvious. I missed then and I was running in circles trying to figure out what's going on. 

Thanks for find!